# Write down an expression in the form $ax^n$ for: $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, radicals

> Write down an expression in the form $ax^n$ for
>
> $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}$$

**What I have tried so far:**

multiplying by the conjugate to give:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h} \cdot \frac{h}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}$$

so we cancel out $h$:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}$$

as $\lim_{h\to 0}$:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+0}-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+0}+\sqrt{x}}$$

giving:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x}}$$

So I'm not sure how you get the numerator to equal $1$ which would give the correct given answer: $0.5x^{-0.5}$

I think I'm missing a simpler method to obtain this answer - any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are we allowed to use the concept of derivatives? It would be solved in 2 steps if we're allowed to do so..

Comment: When you multiply with the conjugate, you need to multiply with $\frac{\sqrt{h+x}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{h+x}+\sqrt{x}}$ not $\frac{h}{\sqrt{h+x}+\sqrt{x}}$ (and if you do this, $h$ will cancel out). The rest is correct.

Comment: You've misunderstood multiplication by conjugates. You need the same factor in the numerator & denominator, otherwise you're not multiplying by $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the concept of derivatives:
We know that:
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
Comparing what we have in the question to this formula, it will be clear to us that what is being asked is essentially:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sqrt{x}$$
Hence we will finally end up with:
$$\boxed{0.5x^{-0.5}}$$
And we're done!

Comment: Usually, this answer is too short for me. However, interpreting the question as an exam question, and seeing the command phrase "write down", this is the fastest approach. So you still get a +1.

Answer (score 8):

$\frac {\sqrt {x+h} -\sqrt x }h =\frac {(x+h)-x} {h(\sqrt {x+h} +\sqrt x)}=\frac 1 {\sqrt {x+h} +\sqrt x}\to \frac 1 {2\sqrt x}=\frac1  2 x^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}$$
Use identity:$(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(\sqrt{x+h})^2-(\sqrt{x})^2}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x+h-x}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}=0.5x^{-0.5}$$